# Does orient DB support group by operation?

Tags: orientdb

I think the answer is no, but i still want to confirm

My use case is as follows:

1)Get sub graph between source and destination. 
2)Then for each node in subgraph obtained in step 1  , do some aggregation
Some thing like

```
select nodeId, sum(mycount) where prop ="value" and prop2 ="value2" and nodeId in [x,y,z ] group by nodeId
```

Can u do  this in orinet DB ?If yes how efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by is supported and it's fast. Have you tried it?

Comment: i read that its not supported .Can you please give a example about how can i use it?

Comment: It's the classic GROUP BY of SQL. Pick any SQL manual/turorial. Just the HAVING clause is not supported yet.